Custom mapping of union (difficult to express)
I have the following union:
type Phone = 'Private' | 'Personal'

How can I map the Phone type to the representation below (if possible):
union([
  literal('Private'),
  literal('Personal'),
])


I think it requires parsing the code and visiting the AST. Are you writing some sort of transpiler?

No. I am using (superstruct union)[https://docs.superstructjs.org/api-reference/types#union} for validation. Just looking a non manual way of validating a union.

What, specifically, do you mean by “map”? Map the type to the representation how? Are you talking about code generation? Are you talking about compilation/transpilation? Please [edit] to clarify.

As stated, it is somewhat difficult to express, but bear with me please. What I am trying to do is given an Union eg Phone (above), how could I get a function to return the representation (union function) or the list of literal function.

If you're having trouble articulating what you want, then please try to provide a more motivating [mre], with multiple examples of how you'd use such a "map". What would the code using it look like? TS doesn't support transpilation of types into JavaScript; types are erased, not "mapped" to the output. If that's what you're asking for, it's not possible. But I don't know if that's what you're asking for, because the question isn't clear. Please [edit] (not comment) to clarify. If you can neither clarify nor demonstrate, what can anyone do but shrug?

@st_clair_clarke I think you should at least explain that you use Superstruct.

@EricMORAND I did say that in my first response with the url pointing the specific usage of superstruct.

Based on comments on the post, it seems like you want to generate runtime information from types. This is not possible. TypeScript types do not exist at all at runtime so you cannot generate things from them.
You would have to hack on the compiler (see https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch), or do what e.g zod does and generate types from function calls, which is possible.

OK!. Thank you. I totally forget typrescript erasure relative to types.
